# Runtime ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: ionic-framework

I got the runtime error and i dont know how to solve it. I dont know what problem with the json. Help me. Thank You in advance.

```html
// providers api
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class PostProvider {
    server: string = "http://localhost/IonicFYP/server.api/"

    constructor(public http: Http){

    }

    postData(body, file){

        let type = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': type });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers});

        return this.http.post(this.server + file, JSON.stringify(body), options)
        .map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the contents of the response. It's likely that you are not receiving a `JSON` object, which is why the parser is failing. Usually, when it starts with `<` it ends up being `HTML`, but it's just a guess.